# Rails, Chosen, Bootstrap: How to apply Bootstrap Styling to a Multiple Select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

Rails: 5.2.1

Ruby: 2.5.1p57

Bootstrap: 4.1.3

I'm trying to add Bootstrap Styling to a Multiple Select field.

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for person do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :firstname %>
  <%= f.input :lastname %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :phone %>
  <%= f.input :tag_list, as: :select, collection: TagList.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :name, input_html: {class: 'chosen-select', multiple: true} %>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The Multiple Select field is the one with "`:tag_list`". Here is how it looks:

[image]

If you compare the "Phone"-field with the "Tag-List"-field, you'll see that the "Phone"-field has Bootstrap Styling, while the "Tag List"-field hasn't.

How can I add Bootstrap Styling to the Multiple Select field?

The Multiple Select field is given by the "`chosen-rails`"-gem. Here is how I implemented it:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'chosen-rails'
```

application.js:

```
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require scaffold
```

application.scss:

```
@import "chosen";
```

scaffold.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  # enable chosen js
  $('.chosen-select').chosen
    allow_single_deselect: true
    no_results_text: 'No results matched'
    width: '100%'
```

Edit:

Thanks to a commenter, it seems to be possible to overwrite the classes of the multiple select field. The following code makes the select field look more like bootstrap:

custom.scss:

```
.chosen-choices {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem !important;
  border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't think bootstrap has tags but does have badges which are similar but not the same.     If you want it to look like bootstrap then you'll have to create your own CSS to style it.  If you search for "bootstrap tags" then there are a number of sites with information on styling tags.

Comment: @MarkDavies I updated my question. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No need to post an answer because you've answered your own question.  Just accept your own answer.  My comment was just a nudge that helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Davies, I found somewhat of a solution.

The chosen library uses the classes "chosen-choices" and "search-choices". It is possible to overwrite these classes with the attribute "!important".

It's not optimal, but now, the field looks more like bootstrap.

Here is my code:

custom.scss:

```
.chosen-choices {
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem !important;
  border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
}
```